# XML in C# - hasAttribute, getAttribute is not there? Why?

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I'm working on a project that requires me to build a game's rooms, items and NPC in a separate database. I've chosen XML, but something prevents me from properly parsing the XML in my C# code. What am I doing wrong?

My errors are these:

```
System.xml.xmlnode does not contain a definition for HasAttribute
```

(this goes for `GetAttribute` as well) and no extension method accepting `'HasAttribute'` accepting a first argument of type `System.Xml.XmlNode` ?

This also goes for `GetParentNode`, and my very last line

```
string isMoveableStr = xmlRoom.GetAttribute("isMoveable");
```

somehow goes:

```
the name xmlRoom does not exist in the current context
```

Here's the method:

```
public void loadFromFile()
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();              // create an xml document object in memory.
        xmlDoc.Load("gamedata.xml");                         // load the XML document from the specified file into the object in memory.

        // Get rooms, NPCs, and items.
        XmlNodeList xmlRooms = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("room");
        XmlNodeList xmlNPCs = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("npc");
        XmlNodeList xmlItems = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("item");

        foreach(XmlNode xmlRoom in xmlRooms) {               // defaults for room:

        string roomID = ""; 
        string roomDescription = "this a standard room, nothing special about it.";                  

        if( !xmlRoom.HasAttribute("ID") )                   //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7.aspx
        {              
        Console.WriteLine("A room was in the xml file without an ID attribute. Correct this to use the room"); 
        continue;                                       //skips remaining code in loop 

            } else {
             roomID = xmlRoom.GetAttribute("id");           //http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acwfyhc7.aspx
            }

        if( xmlRoom.hasAttribute("description") )              
        {
            roomDescription = xmlRoom.GetAttribute("description");
        }

        Room myRoom = new Room(roomDescription, roomID); //creates a room
        rooms.Add(myRoom); //adds to list with all rooms in game ;)

            } foreach(XmlNode xmlNPC in xmlNPCs)
            { bool isMoveable = false;

        if( !xmlNPC.hasAttribute("id") )
        {
            Console.WriteLine("A NPC was in the xml file, without an id attribute, correct this to spawn the npc");
            continue; //skips remaining code in loop
        }

        XmlNode inRoom = xmlNPC.getParentNode();
        string roomID = inRoom.GetAttribute("id");

        if( xmlNPC.hasAttribute("isMoveable") )
        {
            string isMoveableStr = xmlRoom.GetAttribute("isMoveable");
            if( isMoveableStr == "true" )
            isMoveable = true;
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Damnit, sorry. I forgot to include the errors.

I get errors like this: System.xml.xmlnode does not contain a definition for HasAttribute (this goes for GetAttribute as well) and no extension method accepting 'HasAttribute' accepting a first argument of type system.xml.xmlnode ?

Comment: Honestly the `System.Xml` objects are archaic and annoying. I would use `System.Xml.Linq` for this. (Or not use XML at all)

Comment: If  we assume that my knowledge is "less than brilliant": What would System.Xml.Linq require of my code?

Comment: Linq to XML: Start with an `XDocument` or `XElement` instance: `var xdoc = XDocument.Load("gamedata.xml"); var xRooms = xdoc.Descendants("room");`. Then, for instance, you can replace your entire loop which checks for missing ids with this: `if (xRooms.Any(xRoom => (string)xRoom.Attribute("ID") == null)) {Console.WriteLine("A room was in the xml file without an ID attribute...");} else {var rooms = xRooms.Select(xRoom => new Room(xRoom.Attribute("description"), (int)xRoom.Attribute("ID"))).ToList();}`

Comment: @Zev - Awesome example but it must look like ancient Greek to our friend here.

Comment: I actually know ancient Greek ;) 

Anyway, I made it work - mainly by following Bryan Roberts' advice. That does look interesting, though. I'll look at it for another project :) 

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

System.Xml.XmlElement has the function you are looking for.  You are getting XMLNode's.  You will need to cast the nodes to XmlElement to get that function.

```
xmlElement = (System.Xml.XmlElement)xmlRoom;
```

Comment: Ah, thanks!. I should probably mention that I'm fairly new to C#. Where do I place this? I was just going to try different places in the code, but I'd rather learn it proper :)

Comment: If every item in xmlRooms collection is going to be a XmlElement you can just do 
`foreach(XmlElement xmlRoom in xmlRooms) {               // defaults for room:`

Otherwise create a new element like
`System.Xml.XmlElement xmlElement = (System.Xml.XmlElement)xmlRoom;`

and replace all calls to xmlRoom with the variable we created at the begining of the for loop called xmlElement for any item in the collection that matches the elements you want to work with

Comment: Wow. Well, I do have attributes in my XML, so I guess I'll have to try the second suggestion. I'll give it a go.

Comment: This worked, at least for "rooms". I think. Haven't tested it properly, but it seemed to do the trick.

@bryan-roberts: Can you help me with the "xmlRoom does not exist in the current context"-error?

Comment: GetElementsByName returns the XMLNode collection just because it is a base class.  Like many of the functions in that namespace.  So if you need to check if the node it returned is a comment or any other type just use the is comparison.
`if(xmlRoom is System.Xml.XmlElement)`

Comment: Oh, damn. 

@bryan-roberts Now I get an error on  rooms.Add(myRoom); saying Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ... Not sure I'm going to get the hang of this.

Comment: That probably means that rooms was not defined.  rooms is not declared in the snippet you gave.  Maybe you accidentally rearranged your code in such a way to mess that up?

Comment: I fixed this. Rooms was defined, but only after the loadFromFile method had been called --> couldn't save in a rooms list that wasn't there. Switching the methods around worked.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specifically germane to your question, but a response to @ChaosPandion's suggestion and your question in the comments, here is your code example using Linq to XML:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load("gamedata.xml");
var xRooms = xdoc.Descendants("room");
List<Room> rooms;

//If an element doesn't have a given attribute, the Attribute method will return null for that attribute
//Here we first check if any rooms are missing the ID attribute
if (xRooms.Any( xRoom => (string)xRoom.Attribute("ID") == null )) {
    Console.WriteLine("A room was in the xml file without an ID attribute...");
} else {
    rooms = (
        from xRoom in xRooms
        select new Room(
            xRoom.Attribute("description") ?? "this a standard room, nothing special about it.",
            (int)xRoom.Attribute("ID")
        )
    ).ToList();
}

var xNPCs = xdoc.Descendants("npc");
if (xNPCs.Any( xNPC => (string)xNPC.Attribute("id") == null )) {
    Console.WriteLine("A NPC was in the xml file, without an id attribute, correct this to spawn the npc");
} else {
    var npcs = (
        from xNPC in xNPCs
        let inRoom = xNPC.Parent
        select new {
            xNPC,
            inRoom,
            isMoveable = (string)xNPC.Attribute("isMoveable") != null &&
                         (string)inRoom.Attribute("isMoveable") == true
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

Then you can use a simple `foreach` on the `npcs` collection:

```
foreach (var npc in npcs) {
    Console.WriteLine(inRoom.Attribute("ID"));
    Console.WriteLine(npc.IsMoveable);
}
```

OTOH since this code makes use of the `Descendants` method, which returns an collection of `XElement` (the type corresponding to an XML element) and not of `XNode` (the type corresponding to an XML node), the whole issue of a node object not having attributes is neatly sidestepped.

Answer (score 1):

XmlNode does not have methods HasAttribute or GetAttribute. If you look at the MSDN entry for XmlNode, you can see the methods it has available.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.aspx

If you use XmlNode.Attributes["ATTRIBUTE_NAME"] or in your case xmlRoom.Attributes["ID"], you should be able to find the attribute you're looking for. That is, if you would like to continue using XmlNodes.

The following link has an example of how to retrieve attributes by name from an XmlNode:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b823yx9.aspx

Comment: Interesting. I'll try having a look at this.